# Clicking the TableView leads you to the another View

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

I am a newbie to iPhone development. I have already created an `UITableView`. I have wired everything up and included the `delegate` and `datasource`. However, instead of adding a detail view accessory by using `UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailClosureButton`, I would like to click the `UITableViewCell` and it should lead to another view with more details about the `UITableViewCell`.
My view controller looks like this:

ViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController<UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate>{
    NSArray *tableItems;
    NSArray *images;
}

@property (nonatomic,retain) NSArray *tableItems;
@property (nonatomic,retain) NSArray *images;

@end
```

ViewController.m

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController
@synthesize tableItems,images;
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    tableItems = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Item1",@"Item2",@"Item3",nil];
    images = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:[UIImage imageNamed:@"clock.png"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"eye.png"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"target.png"],nil];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    return tableItems.count;
}
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    //Step 1:Check whether if we can reuse a cell
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell"];

    //If there are no new cells to reuse,create a new one
    if(cell ==  nil)
    { 
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyleDefault) reuseIdentifier:@"cell"];
        UIView *v = [[UIView alloc] init];
        v.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
        cell.selectedBackgroundView = v;
        //changing the radius of the corners
        //cell.layer.cornerRadius = 10;

    }

    //Set the image in the row
    cell.imageView.image = [images objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    //Step 3: Set the cell text content
    cell.textLabel.text = [tableItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    //Step 4: Return the row
    return cell;

}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    cell.backgroundColor = [ UIColor greenColor];
}
@end
```

Need some guidance on this.. Thanks.. Please pardon me if this is a stupid question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should implement following method in your UIViewController:

```
 - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

**[Example]**

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
     ExampleDataItem *dataItem = [_dataSource objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];

     DetailViewController *detailViewController = [[DetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"DetailViewController" bundle:nil];
     detailViewController.dataSource = dataItem;

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];
}
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: where does your _dataSource and DetailViewController come from?

Comment: That was just example. In your case, self.tableItems will be the datasource and DetailViewController will be the name of your UIViewController which you will use to present your details view.

Comment: DetailViewController will be the name of your UIViewController which you will use to present your details view. This means that i need to have another ViewController, am i right to say this? For example, SecondViewController?

Comment: Usually yes, but that depends on your context. You can also just create some view, set data on it and add it as a subview to your current view.

Comment: where does your exampledataitem come from? When you say this: You can also just create some view, set data on it and add it as a subview to your current view.? what do u mean? can show me an example?

Answer (score 0):

Implement UITableViewDelegate method `- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`
In side the method just add your detailed `UIView` (assume you globally have reference and allocated this view in viewDidLoad: method) to the `self.view`.Update the contents of the detailed view based upon the `indexPath` selected.You may also want to have a "Done" button on detailed view,which can be used to go back to your table view.

If your application uses `UINavigationViewController` ,have a detailedViewController (of type `UIViewController`) instead of `UIView` and push it on to the navigation controller using:

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:detailedViewController animated:YES];
```

Comment: I do not use UINavigationViewController in my app.. Then how?